# Some Android SDK components does not want to install.Why?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, updates

```
Android 2.2(API8):
-GALAXY Tab by Samsung Electronics,
-Real3D by LGE,
-Dual Screen APIs by KYOCERA Corporation,
Android 2.3.3 (API10):
-Dual Screen APIs by KYOCERA Corporation,
Android 3.1(API12):
-Google TV by Google Inc - this says "Not compatible with Windows"
```

I understand here, but the other ones? I click "Install packages", I can see it loading and installing. It says "Done" but then their status is still "Not installed". I would like that all the available updates to be installed. If anybody has any idea why this happens and how to fix please share it. All the others packages up to Android 4.0 are installed.

Answer (score 1):

I experience the same thing with `Dual Screen APIs by KYOCERA Corporation`, but actually it gets installed even thou it shows up in the list as "Not installed"

Just look in the build target list for your android project and the KYOCERA api should show up there. Don't know about the other packages but it should be the same there

Comment: In the build target I have a lot of `Galaxy Tab Addon` for Samsung(API 8)  and `DTS Add-On ` for Kyocera(API 10). To be honestly I didn't try any of this projects but I imagine that an **Add-On** could'n exist if there is not a basic product that supports an 'addon'. I will try this projects and I will post what I get.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the SDK-Manager with Administrator privileges?

Comment: I used to run it from Eclipse, but I also tried to run it as you say but I get the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

I notice that a package with similar but different name is installed.

Comment: This appears to be fixed in r17